# Missing Push Notification Entitlement aps-environment issue

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I have been trying to upload my app to store but every time I have the issue:

Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the `"aps-environment"` entitlement. If your app uses the `Apple Push Notification service`, make sure your **App ID** is enabled for `Push Notification in the`Provisioning Portal`, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the`"aps-environment"`entitlement. **Xcode 8** does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable`Push Notifications` in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see [Configuring Remote Notification Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1).

I always used same steps to upload my app but after I regenerate the Keys this began to happen. I already try:

> - create new Provision Profile, also renaming
> - uncheck/check Automatically Manage Signing
> - enable Push Notifications on Capabilities
> - reinstall Xcode cleaning all
> - regenerating all keys

Non of them seems to work.
Please, help me!

Comment: is your entitlement file contain `APS Environment` key?

Comment: entitlement file is fine, what seems wrong is that the App Id Prefix on Xcode is different from the Developer Account

Comment: What apple developer account are you signed into within Xcode? Do you have multiple developer accounts?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!
I deleted the file |*appname*|.entitlements from ios file.
Next build was already with aps-entitlements on entitlements.